# Superman throwing the S!

Tags: movie, dc, superman, superman-2

**Was this an original comic book power of Superman or Fortress defence... or was this completely made up by the director Richard Lester?**

There's quite a few sites which talks about this, probably the best two which contradicts one another are these where the first mentions the throwing of the "S" was Lester's invention and the latter describes it being a trap of the Fortress:

- [In the movie Superman II, Superman throws his "S" onto one of the baddies. Was this an innovation for the movie or based on a comic book power?](https://www.quora.com/In-the-movie-Superman-II-Superman-throws-his-S-onto-one-of-the-baddies-Was-this-an-innovation-for-the-movie-or-based-on-a-comic-book-power)
- [What was the deal with that giant cellophane "S" that Superman throws at the bad guys in Superman II?](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090403015630AAJgS8X)

Do we know which is true?

Comment: Why couldn't it be a trap which Lester invented? I don't have the time to search through the entire publication history of Superman to prove a negative, but indications are strong that the cello-shield hasn't appeared in any other medium prior to the movie. The idea of it being a trap in the fortress reeks of hand waving, but even accepting that, the credit/blame still goes to Lester.

Comment: @Politank-Z - You're right in that it could very well be a trap invented by Lester. I think the question is a little misleading, I will edit it to mention if the sheild-throwing was an **original comic book** power/Fortress defence or just a movie creation. Thanks for highlighting that!

Comment: This question is an excellent demonstration of how crappy and unreliable Quora and Yahoo Answers are :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - Ha! Yes, thought I would post it here since I am assuming there's a lot more knowledgable people who use this site :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New powers came and went in the Superman comics over the years (telepathy, telekinesis, freeze breath, super blow, flare, etc.) but throwing the family crest, technically the Kryptonian equivalent of name-dropping or "throwing a title" (e.g. Mission Impossible III's "Did you just throw a title at me?"), never ever appeared in the comics. Nor can the idea be attributed to Richard Lester as it appears in the original [shooting script](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/movies/superman_II_shoot.txt) as follows:

---

> **Non, made furious by the taunt, leaps from his place and springs at Superman.**
>
> **393 EFFECTS: Quickly, in a dazzling display, Superman puts his hand to his chest.**
>
> **Magically, 
>   the "S SHIELD" emblazoned there becomes a literal object in his hand while its "original" 
>   remains on the costume. It shimmers and shines with an energy force that clearly connotes 
>   immense power .**
>
> **Superman flings it like a discus.**
>
> **394 The effect on Non as the "S SHIELD" hits him and wraps around him.**
>
> **395 ON ZOD -- He looks worried. He is beginning to realize that Superman, on his home turf, has powers and devices at his command beyond their comprehension.**

---

The screenplay is attributed to Mario Puzzo (yep...the guy who wrote The Godfather) and to David Newman, Leslie Newman, Robert Benton (un-credited) and Tom Mankiewicz (creative consultant) but no-one's admitted to the S-THROWING idea. In the writer's defense, it does *read* a little better than it was shot and sounds more like a non-lethal high-energy taser-like restraint device rather than the plastic wrap we ended up with.